# arm-linux-androideabi-g++ can not find header cstdarg

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Trying to cross-compile an android app from linux using arm-linux-androideabi-g++, I get an error that the header file cstdarg can not be found.

```
common.h:27:19: fatal error: cstdarg: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

If I look into the /usr/arm-linux-androideabi/include/, the header is not there but other c++ header files are present. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<cstdarg>` is not a system header, in sense that it comes from C++ standard library. Looks like you've missed to add C++ headers to command line. They are placed under `$ANDROID_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/`. Of course ensure that you're using header for appropriate library implementation.

Also you may need to include complier-specific C-headers (at least `<stdarg.h>` as it is used by `<cstdarg>`).

Some of standard headers are compiler-specific because they use some compiler-specific extensions, intrinsics, so on. `<stdarg.h>` is one of them. Because of their nature there is no much sense to put them to generic sysroot include directory. Look under `$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/` directory.